# How to load a WPF resource dictionary at design-time

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a WPF window in which some properties are defined as dynamic resources like this:

```
<Window x:Class="LocSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        MinHeight="350" MinWidth="525"
        Title="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ResId_Title}"
        FlowDirection="{DynamicResource ResId_FlowDirection_Default}" >
    <Grid>
       <Label Content="{DynamicResource ResId_FirstName}" />  
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The `ResourceDictionary` is loaded at runtime to reflect the language choice of the user. And to enable the user to switch the language on the fly.

This works fine at runtime, but at design-time, the resource-defined properties are not shown. It is clear to me that the designer can't show them, because they are not defined at design-time.

I need a way to load a default `ResourceDictionary` at design-time so that the designer can show anything.

Comment: Since this question's a bit old and a lot of these answers are outdated: I want to note that Expression Blend (I don't know if this was permitted in the past) supports design-time styles.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT:

In Blend, you can use a Design-time Resources Dictionary file for this case. Visual Studio can read that file but doesn't have the tooling to create one. But if you're not afraid of project files, you can do that by hand.

1. Add a file DesignTimeResources.xaml to your project.
2. Open your project file (*.csproj) and find registration of the DesignTimeResources.xaml file.
3. Replace this registration with the following code

```
<Page Include="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml" Condition="'$(DesignTime)'=='true' OR ('$(SolutionPath)'!='' AND Exists('$(SolutionPath)') AND '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'!='true' AND '$(BuildingInsideExpressionBlend)'!='true')">
  <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <ContainsDesignTimeResources>true</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>
```

Now you can merge all the resource dictionaries you need in the file. Compiler will ignore it, but the designer won't.

See [not my article](https://github.com/jbe2277/waf/wiki/WPF-Design-Time-Support-(Part-2)) for more details.

Comment: To anyone coming along and reading this..  This will make the designer happy, but you shouldn't actually do this as it will instantiate an extra copy of your resource file every for every instance of a control that directly references the resource.

Comment: Also the question was to load resource dictionary during DESIGNTIME not runtime ... :| (potentially downvote)

Comment: If someone need to have ResourceDictionaries only during DesignTime, then have a look here: https://dennymichael.net/2016/07/28/wpf-design-time-resources-dictionary/ - Was doing the trick for me ... ;))) Thank you Denny Michael

Comment: @claudekennilol I can not confirm this. When I added _normal_ ResourceDictionary-references execution took 10x longer then without. But when I set `ContainsDesignTimeResources` to `true` there was no impact on execution time. I stay with this setting.

Comment: For VS2019 project files: 
<Page Update="Properties\DesignTimeResources.xaml">
  <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  <ContainsDesignTimeResources>True</ContainsDesignTimeResources>
</Page>

Comment: If you paste in a DesignTimeResources.xaml into the Properties folder in VS2019, the ItemGroup gets automatically added for you to .csproj

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the outdated and useless "DesignTimeResources.xaml", In the newest version (VS 2022), you can use more powerful `d:` prefix to include your design time resource:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <d:ResourceDictionary Source="/OTHER_ASSEMBLY;component/Resource/YOUR_DESIGN_TIME_RESOURCE.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/styles/YOUR_COMPILED_RESOURCE.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/OTHER_ASSEMBLY;component/styles/YOUR_COMPILED_RESOURCE2.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
```

Side note:
The `d:` can also be used to set design-time properties on Control, such as `d:Opacity="0.5"`, although it is not listed in IntelliSense...
Authough it can work on many properties, but this is not work:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <d:ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/MANY_DESIGN_TIME_RESOURCE1.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/MANY_DESIGN_TIME_RESOURCE2.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/MANY_DESIGN_TIME_RESOURCE3.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary Source="resources/MANY_DESIGN_TIME_RESOURCE4.xaml" />
    <d:ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Some blog post mentioned that you can write it like this, but I test on latest version of VS and confirmed that it will not take effect on the XAML designer any more.

PS: I confirmed it works on the <del>newest VS 2022</del> [VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/xaml-designtime-data?view=vs-2019), I'm not sure it can works on lower version.
This feature was [briefly mentioned](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/10331224#T-N10345975) in a bug feedback in the Microsoft developer community.