# How to reference/use Resource Dictionary between multiple projects inside solution

Tags: c#, wpf, resourcedictionary

I am building a WPF desktop app with .net framework 4.7.2. and need some help for merging resource dictionaries.

I have 1 solution with 2 projects:

[image: Solution structure]

1. Main parent project (ProcesingDesktopHub) which only has a nav bar and depending on user click its injecting a view/viewmodel from child project (DopisiUzPovrate).

Inside the parent project I have created a ResourceDictionary.xaml with some colors etc. and I want to be able to propagade that dictionary to the child project so it can be used if I run the child project separately from the parent (testing, designing etc.)

I have tried putting this inside the child but it does not work:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://ProcesingDesktopHub:,,,/ProcResourceDictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I hope I described my question correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution cannot have circular references between projects.
Since the parent project refers to the child, then, accordingly, the child cannot refer to the parent in any way.
One of the solutions: move the shared resources (if you need not only resources, but also types, controls, etc.) to a third project that will be referenced by the parent and child projects.

Second variant: if you do not provide for the use of the child project outside the parent project, then you can use the design-time resource creation technique described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17712041/13349759
And in runtime, the resources of the parent project will be used.

> Design time sounds good but I would need to run the parent project for debugging purposes each time if I understood it correctly.

If you want to separately debug a child project, then creating a third project with shared resources will be the best varaint.
In addition, if you ALWAYS use the parent project only together with the child, then pay attention to the answer from @MuhammadSulaiman.

Comment: Design time sounds good but I would need to run the parent project for debugging purposes each time if I understood it correctly. So, I should create a class library I guess and put resources there and reference that library from parent and children projects? Seems to me like that is a better solution.

Comment: I've supplement to my answer. Read this supplement.

Comment: I will create a third shared project which will hold the resources I need so every project inside the solution can reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Move ResourceDictionary.xaml to child project (i.e. DopisiUzPovrate), and the structure of resources in ProcesingDesktopHub (i.e. Application.xaml) would be like this

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/DopisiUzPovrate;component/Path/To/ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Converters, Colors and styles --> 
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**Update:** In case you have one application (ex. ProcesingDesktopHub) and several modules (DopisiUzPovrate1, DopisiUzPovrate2, etc...), and all of these would use shared resources, then you have to create a SharedModule that hosts the shared resources and once you reference the ResourceDictionary.xaml in desktop application, it'd be available to the modules and application at runtime..

Comment: Thanks, but my general idea is that I will add over time more projects (childrens) and different devs will be working it. I dont want them to worry about creating resourcedictionary file and then adding it to the parent merged dictionary as well. They just need to reference it in their project (child) and then use its colors, styles etc.

Comment: This idea is coverd in @EldHasb answer.. I just mention the mechanisme that fits what you've described in the question (in which you have only one library and one app, so you don't have to create another lib for the shared resources)..

Comment: Thank you guys. I am not limited to creating a third shared project, and I will do just that, after reading your inputs. My initial thoughts when asking the question is that I can create a reference between the projects so I thought a separate third project would be an overkill. Don't have the reputations yet, but you have my upvotes :)